# php json decode exception when send data using cURL

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am using laravel as a server API backEnd but when clients send request using cURL I got the following  json decode exception

```
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
```

here is the code of client

```
      $data = [ "items"=>array(
        "order_reference"=> "123412",
          "mode" =>"payment",
            "products" => [array(
            "id"=> 1,
            "product_name"=> "product 1",
            "quantity"=>1,
            "unit_amount"=> 100)
            ]
            
            , "currency"=>"YER",
            "total_amount"=>1500,
            "success_url"=> "https://company.com/success",
            "cancel_url"=> "https://company.com/cancel",
            "metadata"=>[
            "Customer name"=> "somename",
            "order id"=> 0 ]
           
    )];




    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/api/order",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "private-key: rRQ26GcsZzoEhbrP2HZvLYDbn9C9et",
            "public-key: HGvTMLDssJghr9tlN9gr4DVYt0qyBy",
            
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

and this is the code of API backEnd

```
json_decode($request->items,true);
```

and the result of the code is

```
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
```

Comment: debug the `$request->items` string and see if it's valid JSON. It's not hard

Comment: your API consumers should be sending a content type of `application/json`. If that happens and the request body is valid JSON then you do not need to do `json_decode` the backend should do that automatically. The issue here is that the whole body is JSON encoded so `$request->items` is not set at all if the content type is not correct

Comment: the api failed to decode the json i test it and get the json exception format

Answer (score 0):

It should be `json_decode($response->items,true);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this header

> Content-Type: application/json

to your client code in this manner:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       "private-key: rRQ26GcsZzoEhbrP2HZvLYDbn9C9et",
        "public-key: HGvTMLDssJghr9tlN9gr4DVYt0qyBy",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
```

then laravel will automatically decode in the backend and you don't need to use *json_decode*. You can simply use *$request->items* to access to the client's items.